# $(this.form) not getting the form element, what changes should i do?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I am making a sales cart for a point of sale system. 
I have some fields like quantity, rate etc when an item is added POS.
One can make changes to the added item like change the quantity ,price etc.

For building the POS i have used html, css, javascript, jquery, php.

On change of any fields like quantity,price etc i have added a listener to submit the change in background and update the POS accordingly.

Simplified code:

```
<tbody id="cart_contents">
  <?php foreach (array_reverse($cart, true) as $line => $item) {
$cur_item_info = isset($item['item_id']) ? $this->Item->get_info($item['item_id']) : $this->Item_kit->get_info($item['item_kit_id']);
?>
  <tr id="reg_item_top">
    <?php echo form_open("sales/edit_item/$line", array('class' => 'line_item_form')); ?>
    <td id="reg_item_name">
      <center>
        <?php echo $item['name']; ?>
      </center>
    </td>
    <td id="reg_item_qty">
      <?php
echo form_input(array('name' => 'quantity', 'value' => $item['quantity'], 'size' => '2', 'id' => 'quantity_' . $line));
?>
    </td>
  </form>
  </tr>
  <?php }?>
</tbody>
```

Jquery Listener:

```
$("#cart_contents input").change(function()
{
console.log($(this.form));
var toFocusId = $(":input[type!=hidden]:eq("+($(":input[type!=hidden]").index(this) + 1) +")").attr('id');
$(this.form).ajaxSubmit({target: "#register_container", beforeSubmit: salesBeforeSubmit, success: function()
{
salesSuccess();
setTimeout(function(){$('#item').focus();}, 10);
}
});
});
```

The Problem is that the listener function is not calling the ajaxSubmit as its not finding the form.

Can anyone help me here please.

Comment: We can't see the form tag in your code? Post the generated HTML as well, not just the PHP.

Comment: Start with understanding that `this.form` does not select form.

Comment: @u_mulder - of course it does, if `this` is an element inside a form

Comment: Second - generating `form` tag between `tr/td` tags is invalid, so, browser rebuilds your html to make it valid.

Comment: @adeneo Didn't know that, thanks. But it should be clarified that element must be `input`, and not `a`, for example.

Comment: @u_mulder I even tried having the form generating code outside the <tr> but still it dint work

Comment: `form` can be either in `td` or outside `table`. Open generated html and see what you have.

Comment: @adeneo i have edited the question : added the closing form tag